# I'm not getting return value of stored procedure. var @id is not supplied.?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my SQL Server stored procedure to insert data:

```
Alter proc insert_stud1 
    @name varchar(20),
    @mobile int,
    @id int output
as
Begin 
    insert into stud1 values (@name, @mobile)

    set @id = @@identity;
End
```

Corresponding C#

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@name",SqlDbType.VarChar,20);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobile",SqlDbType.Int);
var ret = cmd.Parameters.Add("@i", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value=textBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@mobile"].Value=int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

cmd.CommandText="insert_stud1";

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show(ret.Value.ToString());
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send "@i" instead of "@id"

Answer (score 3):

You need to give correct parameter name and set parameter direction as output

```
SqlParameter idParameter= new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
idParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(idParameter);
```

after the line :`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` result id can be get as below

```
int id = int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: is the name of stored proc. parameter should be same as define in c# code??